# IOS Safari on Ipad vertical center in absolute positioned container

Tags: ios, css, ipad, position, absolute

I have two containers which are positioned absolutely one below the other like so:

```
<header>
    <div class="vcenter">
    ...
    </div>
</header>
<div id="wrapper">
...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
header {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
height: 70%;
}

.vcenter {
position: relative;
margin-top: -50px;
top: 50%;
}

#wrapper {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
top: 70%;
}
```

I'm centering **.vcenter** vertically with relative positioning. This works fine in all major browsers. Only on IOS Safari on the Ipad it's bugging. Check out the [site](http://www.maederproperty.ch/dienstleistungen.html) I'm working on. **.vcenter** is the container of the logo.

I'm inspecting it through Xcodes IOS-Simulator and also checked on an real Ipad. Is this possibly an IOS Safari Bug? Does somebody have a workaround? I want to keep my header dynamically resizing vertically (height: 70%)...

Thanks in advance for your thoughts.

Desktop Screenshot (how it should be):
[image]

IOS-Simulator Ipad Screenshot (how it should't be):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really explain it, but using `position: absolute` seems to fix your problem:

```
.vcenter {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -50px;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%; /* needed to add to fix horizontal positioning */
}
```

I think it has something to do with using `absolute` positioning and percentages on the `header`. If you inspect the height of the `html` & `body`, they aren't actually as tall as your content - so maybe computing a 50% positioning for the vcenter is getting messed up. Not sure...

Comment: Thanks man, exactly what I needed. I forgot the width: 100%, that's why I discarded this solution first. thx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `transform` solution?  It generally covers your bases for things like iOS rendering issues (of which there are several more than just this scenario).

Write your class like this (it'll break for IE9 and below, but that's what browser shimming is for and you can use your existing code for the shim using Modernizr)

```
.vcenter {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
 }
```

That should render `.vcenter` at the vertical center for all modern browsers as well as iOS Safari.

Comment: I already tried this, but unfortunately it doesn't work. `.vcenter` still positions itself strangely. Like IOS could not handle two absolute positioned containers one below the other and positions `.vcenter` on the basis of a false calculated height or something...